# Как сделать чтобы вернуло this[0]

Tags: javascript, функции, dom

Добрый день, мне нужно чтобы javascript вернул innerHTML 1ого элемента через функцию, но он почему-то это не делает. `HTMLElement.prototype` пробовал ничего не выходит если не сложно объясните в чем проблема.

```js
function parsehtml() {
  
    return this[0].innerHTML;
 
}

alert(document.getElementsByClassName('color').parsehtml())
```

```css
fieldset {
  float: left;
}

.colors a:focus:before {
  content: ' > ';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="colors">
  <legend>Краски</legend>
  <a class="no_color" href="javascript:void(0)">Краски не нужны</a><br>
  <a class="color_2" href="javascript:void(0)">Нужно 2 банки краски</a><br>
  <a class="color_1" href="javascript:void(0)">Нужна одна банка краски</a>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `function parsehtml(el) {
  
    return el[0].innerHTML;
 
}

alert(parsehtml(document.getElementsByClassName('color')))`

Comment: Нет, мне нужно чтобы было так `document.getElementsByClassName('color').parsehtml()`

Comment: Тогда тебе придется переопределять `getElementsByClassName` и писать свою, которая ищет элемент и возвращает что-то, на что можно применить данную функцию

Comment: Уже пробовал. Я не понимаю что должна вернуть функция.

Comment: Не надо так делать. Переопределять базовые функции document (как и другие базовые функции) очень плохо. Ищите другое решение или подход.

Comment: В смысле функция которая выбирает элемент

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы это заработало, функцию `parsehtml` нужно добавить в прототип коллекции, которую возвращает функция `getElementsByClassName`

Например так:

```js
HTMLCollection.prototype.parsehtml = parsehtml;

function parsehtml() {

  return this[0].innerHTML;

}

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('color').parsehtml())
```

```css
fieldset {
  float: left;
}

.colors a:focus:before {
  content: ' > ';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="colors">
  <legend>Краски</legend>
  <a class="color" href="javascript:void(0)">Краски не нужны</a><br>
  <a class="color" href="javascript:void(0)">Нужно 2 банки краски</a><br>
  <a class="color" href="javascript:void(0)">Нужна одна банка краски</a>
</fieldset>
```

Но так лучше не делать, так как такой подход чреват конфликтами при частом использовании. Гораздо проще сделать функцию, которая будет принимать коллекцию первым параметром.

Comment: Еее. обезъянки одобряют)

Comment: Спасибо, через 6 минут помечу как правильный, очень полезно.

Comment: Тут должно быть предупреждение о старых версиях IE

Comment: Ну и вообще модификация прототипа native object стандартом не предусмотрена.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я там в принципе написал, что _так лучше не делать_. и вроде как HTMLCollection это не native object?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а что там в старых версиях IE? упадем если попробуем в DOM элементе что-то добавить? или просто ничего не будет?

Comment: @Grundy может что угодно произойти

Answer (score 1):

Расширять нужно не HTMLElement, а HTMLCollection, т.к. getElementsByClassName и пр. возвращают именно его.

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.getHTML = function() {
    return this[0].innerHTML;
};
var html = document.getElementsByClassName("main").getHTML();
```

P.S. эх... не успел))

Comment: Все равно голос вверх поставлю, Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

Comment: Спасибо большое :-)